# What does 레이파니 mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation

When I translated it, the word 레이파니 just translated as Reifany or Leifany but I don't know what that is. Even when I searched for it on google, I didn't find anything.

곧장 레이파니에 맡겨 뒀었지요
I left it straight to Reifany.

Comment: Maybe, 레이파니 is someone's name ? When did you see the word ?

Comment: Oh right it could be that. I saw it from a manhwa.. it was when the character explain that he can't throw away a ring that come down for generation, so he left it to reifany. I thought it maybe there's something like a box that called reifany 

Answer (score 1):

"에 맡기다" is used for a place (e.g. pawnshops, banks, nurseries, shops, and information desks) where people keep theirs, whereas "에게 맡기다" for a person (e.g. babysitters, pawnbrokers, bank clerks, friends, parents, and colleagues) to whom others keep theirs or hand their tasks. Thus, 레이파니 is a place.

I assume that you read a fantasy novel, "아델라이드의 라 돌체 비타." Part of it says, "제국 제일의 보석점 레이파니" (The empire's best jewelry store, 레이파니). It seems that the author used the name of [Tiffany & Co](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_%26_Co.).